# I am trying to run Ionic 4 app in IPhone 5 with Version 10.3.3

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova, ionic-framework, build

I am trying to Run Ionic App with iPhone 5 with version 10.3.3. Its working in Up to version 11, but when i am trying to run app in iPhone 5 then i am getting error..

I attached screenshot.
Screenshot

[image]

Comment: check ur tagretd versionin xcode

Comment: this link may help https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/ionic-webview-plugin-version-compatibility/151218

Comment: I set target version 9.0 then also same error.